# What is typed array and benefit of using typed array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I studied that typed array improve performance. this topic(Typed Array) is new to me. If any one have good explaination or if is there any good tutorial or blog for the typed array the please suggest me. I want to know about :
What is typed array and what is the benefit of using typed array? and what is the difference among `new Int32Array(16)` , `new Int16Array(32)` and `new Uint16Array(32)`

Comment: MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) is a great resource for JS-related information. [MDN on Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays). Google is a great place to find information too.

Comment: You already seem to to know the benefit: Higher performance.

Comment: not necessarily, there are a few caveats, in general, typed arrays should be faster to work with, slower to create (and destroy?)